Proof of Blichfeldt's lemma
Blichfeldt's lemma is the following: for any full-rank lattice $\Lambda$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and any measurable set $D$ whose measure exceeds that of a fundamental domain of $\Lambda$, there exist $x, y \in D$ such that $x - y \in \Lambda$.
Is there a rigorous (measure-theoretic) way to formulate a proof of this statement? Thank you!

We reduce to the case where $\Lambda = \mathbb{Z}^n$, applying a linear transformation as needed. Haar measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is just Lebesgue measure (which we denote here by $\mathrm{vol}$), and is translation-invariant. Then $\mathrm{vol}(\Pi) = 1$.
Write $\chi_{B}$ for the characteristic function of $B$. This function is Lebesgue-integrable because $B$ is a measurable set. Let
$$\phi(x) = \sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}^n} \chi_B(x + m)$$. Because $B$ is bounded, it follows that $\phi$ is bounded, as there are finitely many nonzero terms for any given $m \in \mathbb{Z}^n$.
Now we integrate both sides of this expression over $\Pi = [0, 1]^n$. Thanks to our previous remark, we may freely switch integral and sum because the summation is a finite sum of nonnegative terms, so
$$\int_{[0,1]^n} \phi(x) \mathrm{d}x = \int_{[0,1]^n} \sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}^n} \chi_B(x + m) \mathrm{d}x = \sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}^n} \int_{[0,1]^n} \chi_B(x + m) \mathrm{d}x$$
$$= \sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}^n} \int_{[0,1]^n + m} \chi_B(x) \mathrm{d}x = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \chi_B(x) \mathrm{d}x = \mathrm{vol}(B) > 1$$
This implies that $\phi(x) \geq 2$ for some $x \in [0, 1]^n$, which gives the desired two points.
